# How to go to some controllers method from another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult SearchData(DataClass dc)
        {
            //Some logic
            return PartialView(data);
        }

        public ActionResult Search(DataClass dc)
        {
            //Some logic
            return View(dc);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Info(string edrpou)
        {
            //Some logic
            return View(dc);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Info(DataClass dc)
        {
            // ???
            return View("Search", dc);
        }
}
```

In view `Search.cshtml` I have some forms like

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Param, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "textBox" })
```

to create query string and `<input type="submit" />` to confirm. Then I show some info from db and create link

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.Rows[i]["NAME"], "Info", "Home", new { edrpou = (string)Model.Rows[i]["EDRPOU"] }, null)
```

after pressing it redirected to view `Info.cshtml`. In result I get `/Home/ResultInfo?edrpou=41057472` page with some info and forms like in `Search`
After pressing confirm button in `Info` reference still `/Home/ResultInfo?edrpou=41057472` but I expect to use logic from `Search` after pressing that button.

P.S. `PartialViewResult` triggered in `Search` and it exactly what I need by pressing confirm button in `Info`

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `RedirectToAction`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Info(DataClass dc)
{
    // some specific logic, if any

    return RedirectToAction("Search");
}
```

And because you need to move around the DataClass object, you could also use `TempData`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Info(DataClass dc)
{
    // some specific logic, if any

    TempData['data'] = dc; //of course 'data' is not a good name, use something more specific
    return RedirectToAction("Search");
}

public ActionResult Search(DataClass dc)
{
    if (dc == null && TempData.ContainsKey('data'))
        dc = (DataClass)TempData['data'];

    //Some logic
    return View(dc);
}
```

Alternatively you could just call `Search` directly, but that's not as nice, because it won't redirect user to the correct route: it will appear as though user is still on "info" page while in reality they are already on "search".

Comment: OK, I'll try it tomorrow and post feedback. Thank you for advice, Andrei!

Comment: I tried to do like you said, but after redirect it didn't use TempData. In DataClass are some props, wich filling by selecting some ListBoxFor and TextBoxFor. After redirect I expect to show result with that props, but it shows like all lists is empty.

Comment: @IhorMykytiv, did you debug to make sure `dc` comes into `Info` method with all fields containing expected values?

Comment: Your advice works! Problem was in public PartialViewResult SearchData(DataClass dc), wich take params from DataClass. After I added there check on TempData problem was solved. So thank you! :)